# How to install postgresql-client / psql on Nixos

Tags: postgresql, psql, nix, nixos, nix-shell

I'm wondering how to install the `psql` command on NixOS. To be clear: I'm only interested in the client, not the server.

I've looked at the [derivation](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/96190535e526bc1f7b8975d9f6f2f6493060203f/nixos/modules/services/databases/postgresql.nix) but couldn't find any pointers.

Is there a way to create a derivation without building from source?

Thanks!

Comment: You've found the *NixOS module*. The [derivation is here.](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/servers/sql/postgresql/default.nix). It does not define a client-only derivation. I have double checked with `nix repl '<nixpkgs>'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `psql` command is in any of the `postgresql*` packages, so you can just add that to `environment.systemPackages` and rebuild:

```
environment.systemPackages = [ pkgs.postgresql ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of installing the package you can also use nix [shell](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/command-ref/new-cli/nix3-shell.html) / [run](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/command-ref/new-cli/nix3-run.html), and define a shell alias:

```bash
alias psql="nix shell nixpkgs#postgresql --command psql"
```